# Jquery Select Validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate this select / drop down. I am not getting an error, but the validation is not ocurring. I am using the validation for other fields, which is working fine. Here is my jquery and the select which doesnt want to seem to validate:

```
$().ready(function() {
$("#cancelForm").validate({
    debug: false,
    errorClass: "authError",     
    errorElement: "span", 
    rules: {
        inputString: "required",
        notes: "required",
        end_time: {required: true}
    },
    messages: {
        inputString: "Please enter the membername",
        notes: "Please enter the notes",
        end_time: "Please select a time"
    }
});
});
```

Here is my select:

```
<div class="styled-select">
<select name="end_time" id="end_time">
<option value="">None</option> 
<option value="05:00:00">5:00AM</option>
<option value="05:30:00">5:30AM</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for taking a look at my issue.

Comment: I am not seeing your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/nnxtG/. Validating a select should work fine...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of end_time: {required: true}, write this:

```
end_time: {custom_required: true}
```

And add this custom validation method:

```
$.validator.addMethod("custom_required", function(value, element) {
    return (value) ? true: false;
}, "Please select the end time.");
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can use `required: true` on a select. Because there is always something selected, even if the value is empty.

Maybe try `minlength:1`

Comment: Of course you can put `required` on a `select`.   First `option` must contain `value=""`.